# How to use RestClient - Ruby for my situation

Tags: ruby, rest, header, rest-client

I'm trying to use RestClient with Ruby. I got a curl from Postman, but when I try generate my code in Ruby I had a problem.

curl --location --request GET 'https://url?param1=value1&param2=value2' \
--header 'app_token: token1' \
--header 'user_token: token2' \

I try to do this:

```
require 'rest-client'
def execute
        url = 'https://url?'
        begin
            response = RestClient::Request.new(
                method: :get,
                url: URI.encode(url),

                headers:{
                    content_type: 'application/json',
                    app_token: 'token1',
                    user_token: 'token2',
                    params:{
                           param1:'value1',
                           param2:'value2'
                    }                                       

        }).execute

        rescue RestClient::Unauthorized, RestClient::Forbidden => err
                    puts 'Access denied'                        
                    puts err         
        else
                puts 'It worked!'
                puts response
        end 
end
```

Execution results:

**Access denied**

**401 Unauthorized**

I think Its have something wrong with headers, but don't know how I should code this.

As below I tried it another way and it worked. I don't know to do using RestClient

```
    def execute
        url = URI('https://url?param1=value1&param2=value2')

        https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port);
        https.use_ssl = true

        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
        request["app_token"] = 'token1'
        request["user_token"] = 'token2'

        response = https.request(request)

        response_body = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
    end
```

Comment: What does "I'm receive: 401 Unauthorized" mean? Do you mean you ran your code and the literal output in your console was "401 Unauthorized" and not "Access denied" like you expect? Your [mre] should include the *exact* output you receive when you run your code.

Comment: is this the EXACT code you are using? param2 is missing an apostrophe